# Gravity creates heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, gravity, temperature

There are three sources of heat in the Earth's core, impacts of the planet when it was created (impacts made heat), radioactive decay of elements, and the extreme amounts of pressure and friction created from rocks pressing down on each other because of gravity. The last of which creates heat only because of gravity. This is a violation of conservation of energy in my mind. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Why *would* it be? Frictional heating requires motion, does it not?

Comment: yeah but motion is caused by that annoying gravity boi

Answer (score 2):

here is why gravitational compression does not violate energy conservation:

For a system consisting of (for simplicity) two objects a very large distance apart, the gravitational potential energy of that system is at a maximum. This is because to pull those two objects apart and move them far away from each other in the first place requires the performance of work on the system, which gets stored as gravitational potential energy.

That potential energy is then given up as the two objects fall back towards one another and appears as kinetic energy of motion. At the moment when those two fast-moving objects smack into each other, their gravitational potential energy is at a minimum and their kinetic energy is at a maximum.

Then that kinetic energy goes into smashing up the two impacting bodies, which heats them up, and creates high pressure down in the center of the big cloud of impact fragments.

Energy is conserved at every stage of this process.

Answer (score 1):

> and the extreme amounts of pressure and friction created from rocks pressing down on each other because of gravity.

Can I rephrase?  I wouldn't say that the heat is from "pressure" or "pressing down".  It's because materials *yield* under that pressure and move.

If we have huge pressures on an ideally rigid surface, there's no heat generated.  But if the material underneath deforms or flows, then it will flow to a configuration with lower potential energy.  The difference in potential energy between the two states will be almost entirely converted to heat.

Comment: The temperature increase from pressurizing a large amount of material (to be able to ignore conductive cooling) is at least $(\partial T/\partial P)_S=-(\partial T/\partial S)_P(\partial S/\partial P)_T=-T/mc_P(\partial S/\partial P)_T=T/mc_P(\partial V/\partial T)_P=T\alpha/\rho c_P$, with density $\rho$, constant-pressure specific heat $c_P$ and thermal expansion coefficient $\alpha$. This is separate from yielding; pressure alone doesn't cause yielding. In other words, I don't see how this answer addresses the original question.

Comment: Perhaps you should explicitly state that the yielding is inelastic.